# I want build Calendar app in xamarin, but there is a errors in my code. and I don't know how do I fix this problem

Tags: xamarin, reference, calendar, controls, .net-assembly

This is my code. I put the Calendar reference in my code. but in visual studio shows me this message.
"The type 'conrtols:Calendar' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built"
could any one help me?

````
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XamForms.Controls;assembly=XamForms.Controls.Calendar"
             x:Class="CalendarApp.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <controls:Calendar Padding="10,0,10,0" 
                           SelectedBorderWidth="4" 
                           DisabledBorderColor="Black"
                           ShowNumberOfWeek="false"
                           StartDay="Monday"
                           TitleLabelTextColor="Purple"
                           TitleLeftArrowTextColor="Blue"
                           SelectedDate="{Binding Date}"
                           SpecialDates="{Binding Attendances}"
                           DateCommand="{Binding DateChosen}"/>
    </StackLayout>


</ContentPage>```
````

Comment: are you using some third party nuget package?  If so, it is very helpful to tell us **exactly** which on you are using.  There are multiple calendar controls available and we have no way of knowing which one you have chosen.

Comment: I'm using the XamForms.Controls.Calendar

Comment: Did u add NuGet package of XamForms.Controls.Calendar into your project?

Comment: did you add the nuget package in all projects?  Did you follow all the instructions for setup and initialization?

Comment: Oh I didn't add NuGet package into my all projects. Thank you guys